# get my restful service response null by using OKHttp

Tags: android, okhttp, restful-url

i am new in android and i am getting service response null but service URL is running OK in browser.when i run my app screen shows blank and no data come from services where i am doing wrong kindly help me.

my fragment:

```
public class SpecificCountryScholorshipsFragment extends Fragment  {

OKHttpRequest okHttpRequest = new OKHttpRequest();
ArrayList<ScholorshipsModel> arrayList;



ListView                        list
/***********************************************************************************/

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {

        String  getResponse = okHttpRequest.doGetRequest("http://192.168.100.7/scholar/web/app.php/scholarship");
        if (getResponse != null) {
             //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(getResponse);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ScholorshipsModel model = new ScholorshipsModel();
                model.setScholorship_name(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                model.setScholorship_detail(jRealObject.getString("details"));
                model.setScholorship_pic(jRealObject.getString("picture"));

                arrayList.add(model);
                setAdapterValue();

            }


        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scholorship_listing_main, container, false);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Scholorshiplist);



        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List is clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScholorshipDetailActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return null;
}



    /***********************************************************************************/

private void setAdapterValue() {
    ScholorshipAdapter adapter = new ScholorshipAdapter(getActivity(),  R.layout.scholorship_listing, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

OKHttp class:

```
public class OKHttpRequest {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");


public String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {

    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return null;

}



String doPostRequest(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}}
```

Comment: if you are using PHP service and you are just echo the statement there you get the response on browser but not  when you call the api from mobile so please check your service

Comment: service is working ok but when i call it from android its give null response @NoumanShah

Comment: your are not getting response form service so  i think error should be in service

Answer (score 0):

Check your API first by [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), I think your are missing some parameter in Hader or may be in body due to it response is not coming from server. Also I am recommending user [volly](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for Client - Server Communication

Comment: In POSTMAN my service is running OK @DynamicMind

Comment: Try to send JSon/String request using volly then check then put log int both onResponse and OnError method, I hope in this way we can find where is the problem, client side and server side

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use Rest-client (Add on of Chrome ans Firefox) and if working all fine try with [HttpsURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) it may help you better.